# Django, should I be paranoid to use the ORM's `first()` method for certain scenarios?

Tags: django

I have the following models:

```
class Merchant(Model):
    name = CharField()

class OrderItem(Model):
    merchant = ForeignKey(Merchant)
    freight_item = ForeignKey(FreightItem)

class FreightItem(Model):
    amount = DecimalField()
```

Let's say it's a business rule that all order items that points to the freight item belong to the same merchant, in other words a merchant will only generate one freight item.

In my existing `FreightItem` class, to get the merchant, I am using a property to return the first order item to access the merchant, like this:

```
class FreightItem(Model):
    amount = DecimalField()

    @property
    def merchant(self):
        return self.orderitems_set.first().merchant
```

When I read this code, something in my mind that it's yelling me it's not right. But the other option is to add merchant field into the `FreightItem` model:

```
class FreightItem(Model):
    merchant = ForeignKey(Merchant)
    amount = DecimalField()
```

But this seems redundant(denormalized) in the table.

Which way would you guys prefer?

Answer (score 0):

The `.first()` call is going to fail (None will be returned) if you have a `FreightItem` that has never been part of an `OrderItem`.

Why not do something like:

```
class OrderItem(Model):    
    freight_item = ForeignKey(FreightItem)

    @property
    def merchant(self):
        return self.freight_item.merchant

class FreightItem(Model):
    amount = DecimalField()
    merchant = ForeignKey(Merchant)
```

Comment: An `OrderItem` makes more sense to have direct relationship to `Merchant`.